# Birt viewer to a Maven project for birt 4.3.1

Tags: maven, birt

Hi Iam new to birt and maven .Could any one help me how to convert a birt viewer as a maven project which needs be deployed in weblogic.Any suggestion or tutorial links will be a great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question is overly broad for this site, please read [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create with this folder structure and create xml file named pom.xml .
Download the Birt runtime and you can find a birtviewer example (WebViewerExample).

```
  .WebViewerExample(Root Folder)
     .src
        .main
            .webapp
                .WEB-INF
                    .lib
                    .web.xml
                    ..(other files)
                .new_report_1.rptdesign
                ...(other files)
    .pom.xml
    .target
    .weblogic-maven-plugin.jar
```

Download BirtReportFramework and copy the jar files having names with 'org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda' from  birt-report-framework-4_3_1\eclipse\plugins to WebViewerExample\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib

In command prompt got to  Root folder here 'WebViewerExample' and run mvn clean install.
If you get maven error for missing or unable to download any jar files .No worries..you google the jar location in the maven website and download the jar manually and real trick is placing the jar at correct place inside your maven repository.
For Example if the error is like "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse"

Go to Maven repository whose path is like .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-eclipse-plugin\2.9

Inside 2.9 folder place the maven-eclipse-plugin-2.9.jar and maven-eclipse-plugin-2.9.pom.
Also try to download and place the dependent jar and pom if the maven not get for you due to some problem..

My pom.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.webviewer</groupId>

     <artifactId>WebViewerExample</artifactId>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Birt Viewer Maven Project</name>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
      <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version> 
      <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version> 
      <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
      <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version> 
 </properties>

 <repositories>
                <repository>
                <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
                <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
  <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                </repository>

                    <repository>
                           <releases>
                              <enabled>true</enabled>
                           </releases>
                           <snapshots>
                              <enabled>false</enabled>
                              <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                              <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
                           </snapshots>
                           <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
                           <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
                           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
                        </repository>
 </repositories>

<dependencies>


        <dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.1.v20130918-1142</version>
<!--<version>4.3.1</version> -->
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
     <build>

            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                            <!-- <packagingIncludes>/*.rptdesign</packagingIncludes> 
                             <packagingIncludes>/*.jsp</packagingIncludes>
                             -->
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/org.apache.xerces-2.9.0.jar</packagingExcludes>

                                    <source>1.6</source>
                                    <target>1.6</target>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </plugin>


                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                      <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                      <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>Apache_Tomcat_7_x86</server>
                        <path>/birtviewer</path>
                      </configuration>
                    </plugin>

         </plugins>

</build>
```

Thanks,
Winds